# Remove html extension from url using mod rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, file-extension

I have used mod rewrite to change this url:

```
http://example.com/first.php?second=third
```

To:

```
http://example.com/third.html
```

Using this:

`RewriteRule ^([^/]*)\.html$ /first.php?second=$1 [L]`

How can I remove the `.html` file extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```